# Dataframe query fails after upgrading to spark 2.3.1

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following snippet of scala which mirrors what I used to do in spark 2.1.1:

```
  val headers = Seq(StructField("A", StringType), StructField("B", StringType), StructField("C", StringType))
  val data = Seq(Seq("A1", "B1", "C1"), Seq("A2", "B2", "C2"), Seq("A3", "B3", "C3"))
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(data).map(Row.fromSeq)
  sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, StructType(headers)).registerTempTable("TEMP_DATA")

  val table = sqlContext.table("TEMP_DATA")
  table
    .select("A")
    .filter(table("B") === "B1")
    .show()
```

In 2.3.1 this throws the following error:

```
Resolved attribute(s) B#1604 missing from A#1603 in operator !Filter (B#1604 

= B1).;;
!Filter (B#1604 = B1)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [A#1603]
         +- SubqueryAlias temp_data
            +- LogicalRDD [A#1603, B#1604, C#1605], false

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) B#1604 missing from A#1603 in operator !Filter (B#1604 = B1).;;
!Filter (B#1604 = B1)
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Project [A#1603]
         +- SubqueryAlias temp_data
            +- LogicalRDD [A#1603, B#1604, C#1605], false
```

I can fix this if I swap the `select` and `filter` around.  My question is, why has this changed?  I need to explain why it's happened, and ideally link them to documentation supporting it.

My understanding is that the select returns a dataframe that functionally only has the column `A` in it, so you can't filter on `B`.  I've tried to recreate this issue in pyspark, but it seems to work just fine there.

Here is the stack trace:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1458)
```

Comment: Let me do some research and I'll get back to you on this particular query.  If its a regression, I'll file a spark jira

Comment: Ooh that's worrying.  I will take a look further then.  My codebase has a lot of it's own catalyst rules, though I'm not expecting any to have been triggered by the above code.

Comment: when i read that part of code that is generating this error, I'd say that it's an expected behavior but what i don't understand is that why was it working in the first place...

Comment: probably subject for a JIRA.

Comment: Its working for me on spark 2.3.1 with scala and no additional catalyst rules.  The filter should get pushed before the select.  Whats the explain plan in 2.1.1 and in 2.3.1?  Replace show() with .explain and let us know. Heres mine, comment won't let me format it correctly.  
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [A#48]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(B#49) && (B#49 = B1))
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[A#48,B#49,C#50]

Comment: Ok upon further inspection I cannot figure out why this is working in spark-shell, but not in my case.  I've attached a partial stack trace to my original post, but the error is occurring at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis#289 because `o.missingInput.nonEmpty` is true.  `o` in this case is a Filter with references of B, and it's inputSet comes from an AnalysisBarrier which is returning the set `A`.  I've totally disabled my custom optimization rules and strategies.